# Best way to merge/patch changes between different git repos

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I've been unable to find an adequate solution to this problem, so any help would be appreciated. Here is the setup:

1. We have an SVN repo. That repo is also mirrored to a git repo `git_svn_mirror`.
2. A branch `svn_branch` was created in the SVN repo.
3. Work was done in `svn_branch`, including merging up from trunk several times.
4. A new git repo `git_from_svn_branch` was created from `svn_branch`.
5. Work was done in `git_from_svn_branch`.
6. We now need to merge HEAD of `svn_trunk` into `git_from_svn_branch`.

Diagram:

```
[git_svn_mirror] [SVN]                [git_from_svn_branch]
      |  <-mirror  |
      |  <-mirror  |
      |  <-mirror  |-\                        \
      |  <-mirror  | |                        |
      |  <-mirror  |-|                        |
      |  <-mirror  | |  --> (move to git) --> | (kept branch history only)
      |  <-mirror  |                          |
      |  <-mirror  |                          |
      |  <-mirror  |                          |
      |  <-mirror  |                        HEAD    <----
      |  <-mirror  |                                    |
    HEAD         HEAD                                   |
                                                        |
     ^            ^                                     |
     |____________|__ how do we get one of these, into  |__ this (or vice-versa)
```

Ignoring the issues that caused us to arrive at this situation ("why was a 2nd git repo created", etc) what is the best solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git remote add git-from-svn-mirror its://repo/url
git fetch git-from-svn-mirror

git merge git-from-svn-mirror/master
```

should do it.

Comment: I just get hundreds upon hundreds of conflicts. Possibly because we merged up from trunk when still in SVN? I'm not sure why else there would be that many conflicts, there were only a couple dozen files modified in that repo.

Comment: Only actual differences can cause conflicts -- diffs are created on-demand.  Did whitespace change, line-terminator conflicts, leading tabs?  There's a depressing thought.  Whatever, it looks like you're going to have find out where they came from and resolve them yourself.